# What is the best way of monitoring GPU temperature in Xubuntu 14.04 when using the OpenSource driver?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, temperature, gpu, xfce-panel

I had a severe problem with GPU temperature in 12.04 and even later, and even if that seems gone in 14.04, I want to keep an eye on my GPU.

Is there a program that would display that, in the xfce-panel or otherwise?

---

### EDIT:

After installing `lm-sensors` and the Xfce panel Sensors Plugin, I can see some temperatures

[image]

but not the GPU. I use the Ubuntu radeon driver.

[image]

Also, I have installed `psensor`: but no GPU

[image]

Also, running `sensors` in Terminal that info is not available:

[image]

### **EDIT2:**

At [this](http://wpitchoune.net/gitweb/?p=psensor.git;a=blob_plain;f=README.html;hb=HEAD#_ati_amd_gpu_support) Psensor page it reads:
*When the OpenSource ATI driver is used, the monitoring information is available throw lm-sensors ....*

I have installed lm-sensors and following [this advice](http://youtu.be/Sh9YIcEWf2s) I ran `sensors-detect` and answered `yes` to all questions there. In Psensor window now there is a new entry, and it's for **radeon**, but it's always zero.

[image]

Editing the names so as to display the chip name, it looks like so:

[image]

`sensors` command gives the same info as above.

### EDIT3

Also:

```
~$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
[sudo] password for cip: 
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

---

### EDIT4:

```
~$ xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0x6c 0x44 X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x6c
  Serial number of failed request:  17
  Current serial number in output stream:  18
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`?

Comment: @Rmano - edited to add output

Comment: As you can see the ATI card is off (status `DynOff`) --- this is why you have a 0 in the reading. I will edit the answer to show how to switch it on.

Comment: @Rmano - I think I got it.

Comment: @Rmano - added that. sorry for delay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `xfce4-sensors-plugin`:

[image]

It needs [`lm-sensors` installed and configured](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto), and it is in the standard (universe) repository.

The ATI sensor (when used with the radeon open source driver) should be called something like `radeon-pci-0100` --- Notice however that with recent kernels the card is kept off when not used, so the sensor is not read in that conditions --- see https://askubuntu.com/a/469439/16395

You can check if the sensors are working activating the offloading as explained in this post: http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/enable-and-use-open-source-radeon-drivers-in-a-muxless-hybrid-graphics-intelamd-setup/:

1. List the graphic providers:

   ```
   xrandr --listproviders
   ```

   make a note of the `id` hexadecimal codes
2. Activate them:

   ```
   xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0x53 0x79
   ```

   (you have to substitute the codes of the Intel and ATI providers, in that order)
3. Open a terminal window and run

   ```
   DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
   ```

Now using `sensors` in another window you should see the temperature reading of the radeon card going up.

Comment: i have that and see what you displayed in image. but is that the gpu? under sensors type radeon there is nothing for me. maybe because of not using the ATI driver?

Comment: No, this is not the GPU. Now I do not have the ATI laptop with me (the screenshot id from one with an intel graphics). Should be called  `radeon-pci-something`, as  http://askubuntu.com/a/469439/16395

Comment: edited answer. i think the proprietary driver is needed to access that ?

Comment: I can read it with the radeon driver; I will check on the laptop this evening at home but the linked answer was copy-and-pasted from there and I have no proprietary drivers installed. You should check that one --- maybe the radeon is off and nothing is shown; try to type `sensors` in the command line

Comment: I have updated again

Comment: `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0x53 0x79` gives me `Could not find provider with XID 0x53`. But `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info` starts the ATI discrete and the temp goes up in the sensor panel. I have posted an answer on Psensor after I understood your explanation. As seen there, Psensor is slower in refreshing if refreshing at all. The plugin is the answer. It may also need some refreshing after the ATI is stopped, but it  starts soon when the ATI starts.

Comment: You have to adapt the 0x53 0x79 to what the previous command gave you --- they will differ from machine to machine. But if it works that means that it is enabled by default (as should be).

Comment: I think it's ok, I mean I see GPU temperature when ATI discrete running. - But there is some error after the command you last mentioned I think. I'll add an update in question if you want to take a look there.

Comment: "Notice however that with recent kernels the card is kept off when not used, so the sensor is not read in that conditions" this single sentence fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

After doing all those actions that are presented in the question and also after updating Psensor to version 1.1.2 the Radeon temperature appeared there after reboot.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jfi/psensor-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

More here: [Psensor Updated With Option To Display Temperature Sensors On The Panel](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/psensor-updated-with-option-to-display.html).

[image]

### UPDATE:

The radeon info appeared in Psensor only after reboot **if set to launch on startup**. Also, it is odd that if Psensor is closed and restarted without reboot, the `radeon` entry is absent again.

In fact the ATI card is not working at that moment [as this answer explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/469439/47206): *New kernel 3.13 has an advanced dynamic power management of the ATI card with the radeon driver. In normal conditions the ATI discrete is off*.

Both Psensor and Xfce Sensor plugin will display the radeon temperature at startup if they are open but if they are restarted the entry will be missing in Psensor, will be zero in the Xfce panel plugin and will be N/A when running `sensors`.

To test this, and start the ATI card, that answer says to run `glxgears`:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
```

[image]

What happens then is that the Xfce panel plugin will show the GPU temperature, **while psensor will not until restarted**. `sensors` command will display the temperature of the ATI card.

If `glxgears` is shut down, the discrete card will stop. Then, Psensor will continue to show the last GPU temperature until restarted. The panel plugin too, but not for long. In its properties, radeon temp is already zero, uncheck and recheck to refresh.

Comment: note that you should not left click the panel icon but right -> settings instead. the former is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a small python script which could be used in your XFCE panel to monitor the GPU temp, Utilization, Fan speed, Memory and Power based on gpustat https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat.

You can check it out in my repository

https://github.com/Paptop/XfceGpuPanelMonitor