# How to disable my APU and use the GPU (AMD Radeon) open source driver instead?

Tags: ati, graphics, intel-graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 1410 (Kernel v3.13)

```
#uname -r
3.13.0-27-generic
```

I've been trying to disable the APU (i.e. Intel's graphics software driver) and use the GPU (i.e. Xorg open source driver for Radeon) instead. But I failed.

From all the links I visited I only found out that the GPU has been disabled (i.e. **DynOff**)

```
#sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
[sudo] password for mgelbana: 
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

**DIS:** Discrete graphics card

**IGD:** Integrated graphics card

I've also enabled radeon's dynamic power management (DPM) in the kernel parameters (i.e. **radeon.dpm=1**)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.debug=0xe plymouth:debug radeon.dpm=1"
```

To know which driver is currently working, I open Ubuntu's `Settings > Details` and check the following information in the **Overview** section:

```
Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
```

So how can I enable the open source Radeon driver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found a way to activate it dynamically when needed; this answer is a rewording/restructuring of my two previous answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469359/very-low-temperature-reading-for-graphics-driver-using-lm-sensors) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536469/what-is-the-best-way-of-monitoring-gpu-temperature-in-xubuntu-14-04-when-using-t) --- these were more oriented on the temperature sensors on the ATI card so I think it's worthwhile to post this answer here.

In recent (3.13+) kernel the discrete driver is normally disabled:

```
[:~/Pictures/2014] 1 % sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

...but ready to start when needed. To enable the offloading of graphical tasks to the discrete card, you have to [enable it before](http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/enable-and-use-open-source-radeon-drivers-in-a-muxless-hybrid-graphics-intelamd-setup/):

1. List the graphic providers:

   ```
   xrandr --listproviders
   ```

   which gives:

   ```
   Providers: number : 2
   Provider 0: id: 0x79 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
   Provider 1: id: 0x53 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:radeon
   ```

   ...and sometime duplicate entries with the same `id`. 
   Make a note of the `id` hexadecimal codes and
2. activate them:

   ```
   xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0x53 0x79
   ```

   (you have to substitute the codes of the ATI and Intel providers, in that order --- at least I think)

Now you can activate the card for a graphical application by setting the `DRI_PRIME` environment variable. For example by opening another windows and starting `glxgears` in it:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
```

and check again *while the above is running*, you should  have:

```
[:~/Pictures/2014] % sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

which means that the card is ON.

A lot of info is from this [Arch forum entry](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177254) and [this Arch doc page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI#Dynamic_power_management) (hat off to Arch for the quality of documentation and for having it up-to-date...).

Comment: None of these commands worked as expected. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Now that I've upgraded to 15.10, it works :)

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana nice to see you here as well. saw you earlier in the calcite mailing list :)